# Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method, or client not authorized for any of the scopes requested. - Google API

Tags: laravel, google-api, service-accounts, google-my-business-api

I am working on Google API. Created service account, and added client_id in workspace account with scope.(Domain-wide Delegation)
Scope - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/business.manage
Client ID - Numeric Value From Service Account Page

But still showing this error when I give, gmail account. If I give workspace account mail, it will work.

Domain Verification in APIs & Services ( Developer Console) Not completed.

[image]

Please look into this.

```html
        $client = new \Google_Client();
        $client->setApplicationName("Google My Business");
        $client->setSubject('test***@gmail.com');
        $client->setAuthConfig('secret.json');
        $client->setApiFormatV2(2);
        $client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/business.manage");
        $client->setAccessType('offline');
        $client->authorize();

        $service = new \Google_Service_MyBusiness($client);
        $result_accounts = $service->accounts->listAccounts()->getAccounts();
        $locations =  $service->accounts_locations->listAccountsLocations($result_accounts[0]['name']);
         dd($result_accounts);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to deligate to a user it must be a user on your domain

```
$client->setSubject('test***@gmail.com');
```

A standard gmail user can not be delegated to from your domain.